# Difference between BEGIN/END and EXEC

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

what is the difference between

```
Begin
 bc_any_package_pkg.anyProcedure;
End;
/
```

and

```
EXEC bc_any_package_pkg.anyProcedure;
/
```

I can't find if there is any difference...

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`EXECUTE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve022.htm#i2697931) (short `EXEC`) is a SQL*Plus command that basically wraps a `BEGIN END` block around your one-liner:

> Executes a single PL/SQL statement. The `EXECUTE` command is often
>   useful when you want to execute a PL/SQL statement that references a
>   stored procedure.

They really are the same when using SQL*Plus, although `exec` is faster to type.

This is not standard PL/SQL, which means that if you use any other tool than SQL*Plus, there is a chance that `exec` will not be recognized. It also only works with single lines.

Whereas `BEGIN END` is standard and will work with any tool that interfaces with PL/SQL. Such blocks can also span more than one line.

Comment: `exec` also doesn't replace the SQL*Plus buffer, as a normal `begin ... end` block would; so it's handy for things like changing the value of a `variable` bind value between runs of a query.

Comment: @AlexPoole Does exec require the / (slash)?

Comment: @Roland - no; it will re-execute whatever was in the command buffer *before* the `exec` ran, so it's potentially dangerous. (As I said before, `exec` doesn't replace the buffer; run a query, do an `exec`, then `list` the buffer to see that.)

Answer (score 1):

`EXEC` (or `EXECUTE` in its full form) is a [SQL Plus command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve022.htm#i2697931) that executes a single PL/SQL statement.  So it achieves exactly the same effect as writing an anononymus block of PL/SQL.

Comment: Does exec require the / (slash)?

Comment: No it doesn't need the slash